# How can I keep grid.arrange from cutting off x-axis labels on 4 panel plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 figures that I would like to make into a single plot. I can do so by making the figures in `ggplot` then converting them to grobs to use in `grid.arrange`. However, `grid.arrange` seems to cut off the x-axis labels of the bottom-left and bottom-right figures, which in this case should be dates. Any ideas on how to keep the `grid.arrange` from cutting off the x-axis labels of this 4-panel plot?

The final product should look like this, with the axes all aligned and with the same width and height.
[image]

Reproducible Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 7))
x <- c("Date", "Value")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$Date <- seq(as.Date("2021-08-01"), as.Date("2021-08-07"), by = "day")
set.seed(321)
df1$Value <- rnorm(7,20,2)

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 7))
colnames(df2) <- x
df2$Date <- seq(as.Date("2021-08-01"), as.Date("2021-08-07"), by = "day")
df2$Value <- rnorm(7,19,2)

df3 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 7))
colnames(df3) <- x
df3$Date <- seq(as.Date("2021-08-01"), as.Date("2021-08-07"), by = "day")
df3$Value <- rnorm(7,7,1)

df4 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 7))
colnames(df4) <- x
df4$Date <- seq(as.Date("2021-08-01"), as.Date("2021-08-07"), by = "day")
df4$Value <- rnorm(7,10,3)

p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(Date,Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")
p2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(Date,Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")
p3 <- ggplot(data = df3, aes(Date,Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black", angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")
p4 <- ggplot(data = df4, aes(Date,Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black", angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")

g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g3 <- ggplotGrob(p3)
g4 <- ggplotGrob(p4)

g2$widths <- g1$widths
g3$widths <- g1$widths
g4$widths <- g1$widths

g3$heights <- g1$heights
g4$heights <- g1$heights

grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4, ncol = 2) #cuts off x-axes labels of g3 and g4
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the patchwork package?

Comment: I have not heard of the patchwork package. I did just try using it but it did not keep all the plots the same width. Specifically, the top two plots were wider than the bottom two plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of the patchwork package (assuming you've already ran the code in the question). As you can see, the top two plots are not wider than the bottom ones.

```r
library(patchwork)
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I had not used the `plot_layout(ncol = 2)` when I was tinkering with the `patchwork` package. This solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `plot_grid` with `align = 'hv'` argument from `cowplot` package.

**Update: (see comments OP):**

```
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2, align = "hv")
```

[image]

**First answer:**

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, align = 'v')
```

[image]

Comment: I was having similar issues trying to use `cowplot` as I was with the `grid.arrange` function because as you can see the height of the top two plots is greater than those of the bottom two plots. IMO that `patchwork` package really made life easier with it's ease of implementation.

Comment: Ok thank you tor this information. I even didn't realized the difference. I will edit. Please see my update in 1 min.